# JavaScript decorators HOWTO?

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype, decorator

I need to decorate a 3rd party function that I can't modify so I will need to decorate it in any way. I found that in Prototype there is something to do it easily [1].

Is there any alternative to that in jQuery or in plain JavaScript?

[1] http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Function/prototype/wrap/

Comment: NOTE: Need to do it with jquery or plain js, can't add another js framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about your scenario requires a library?  It seems that with native javascript, you could simply:

- Save a copy of the original function
- Create a modified version of the function which uses the original
- Store a reference to the modified version where the original was originally stored.

Comment: What you mean with save a copy of the original?
Something like this?
<code>
new_func = originalFunc
function myExtendedVersion() {
  // do my stuff
  new_func();
  // do my stuff
}
</code>

Comment: yeah, then set originalFunc = myExtendedVersion.

Answer (score 1):

With jquery, it would be pretty easy to just add in another function to use. Try something like:

```
//Sample function you're wrapping around 
function say_hi(){
    alert('hi');
}

//quick jq plugin
jQuery.fn.functionWrap = function(arg,opts){
    if(opts.before && typeof(opts.before)=='function'){
        opts.before();
    }
    arg();
    if(opts.after && typeof(opts.after)=='function'){
        opts.after();
    }
};


//sample function to use the wrapper func
function btnPress(){
    $().functionWrap(
        say_hi,
        {
            before : function(){ alert('happens before'); }, 
            after : function(){ alert('happens after'); } 
        }
    );
}
```

Try adding that to your page, and something like this to test it out:

```
<input type="button" value="asdf" onClick="btnPress();" />
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: This will do it, thanks. But I found that the accepted answer is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I like the wrap functions provided by libraries:  Prototype has the wrap function.  In ExtJS, one might use createDelegate or createInterceptor.  Dojo has declarative AOP.  Sans framework, one might do this:

```
myFunction(){
   something();
   thirdParty.call();  // or apply
   perhapsSomethingElse();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with the jquery AOP plugin: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-aop/

Code would look like:

```
jQuery.aop.around( {target: window, method: 'originalFunc'}, 
  function(invocation) {
    // do your stuff
    invocation.proceed(); 
    // do your stuff
  }
);
```

Answer (score -1):

I will go for *Frank Schwieterman* solution:

```
new_func = originalFunc
function myExtendedVersion()
{ 
  // do my stuff
  new_func();
  // do my stuff 
}
```